# prevent direct url access

Tags: php

I have a website and all the connectivity (with the database and other) are in a folder. Although there is a session on the restricted pages to prevent not logged users, these files may be reached if typed the full url(even if the php does show anything i guess its not a good thing). And the folder itself can be seen like a directory on the server, which is very bad.

```
www.mysite.com/connectionfolder
```

How can I deal with this problem? thanks!

Comment: What server do you use? Apache?

Comment: To restrict access you might want to take a look into .htaccess file (if you use Apache).  Something else you may want to consider, move your database and any includes to a folder outside of your webroot.

Comment: do you want to completely disable direct access, even for logged in users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache: Add the line below in your root `.htaccess` file

`Options -Indexes`

If there is a line `Options Indexes` already in existing `.htaccess` file than you can simply modify it with `Options -Indexes`

This will have Apache preventing direct directory access.

Comment: while i include that file in another file at that time i am not able to use that file,
I mean i have ajax_user.php file and while ajax call i am not able to ACCESS this file using (.htaccess)

Answer (score 2):

If you use Apache put a .htaccess file in your root web directory if one is not already there. Then put this in the file:

```
Options -Indexes
```

More info: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options

Answer (score 2):

You can also redirect the user away from the "secure" pages

```
<?php
//...Valid user check
if(!$validuser)
{
    header("Location: /");
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php header("Status: 404 Not Found"); ?>
```

Put this after session verification, the page with give 404 page error saying page not found

For example you can put it in

```
if(!$user_loggedin) {
header("Status: 404 Not Found");
} else {

echo "welcome to your page ....";


}
```

The above code will generate PAGE NOT FOUND ERROR if the user is not loged in. Which means, anyone seeying that error will thik the page does not exist at all